# Simple Java network IO is not working for large data

Tags: java, io, network-programming

I'm experiencing a strange problem that does not appear on MACOS but only linux...
When I run the following code in linux, i sometimes get an inconsistent message.
The code just create two thread, where one sends a lot of byte array with all 1's to the other, and the other thread just check if all the contents are 1's. It happens occasionally(seems it depends on n..) that it receives 0.

Can someone help me out?

```
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    public class TestIO {
        static final int n = 500000;
        final static byte d  = 10;

        static class SenderRunnable implements Runnable {
            SenderRunnable () {}
            private ServerSocket sock;
            protected OutputStream os;

            public void run() {
                try {
                    sock = new ServerSocket(12345);            // create socket and bind to port
                    Socket clientSock = sock.accept();                   // wait for client to connect
                    os = clientSock.getOutputStream();  

                    byte[] a = new byte[10];
                    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
                        a[i] = d;

                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        os.write(a);
                    }
                    os.flush();

                    sock.close(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        static class ReceiverRunnable implements Runnable {
            ReceiverRunnable () {}
            private Socket sock;
            public InputStream is;
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sock = new java.net.Socket("localhost", 12345);          // create socket and connect
                    is = sock.getInputStream();

                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        byte[] temp = new byte[10];
                        is.read(temp);
                        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
                            if(temp[j] != d){
                                System.out.println("weird!"+" "+i+" "+j+" "+temp[j]);
                            }
                    }
                    sock.close(); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }


        public static void test1Case() throws Exception {
            SenderRunnable sender = new SenderRunnable();
            ReceiverRunnable receiver = new ReceiverRunnable();
            Thread tSnd = new Thread(sender);
            Thread tRcv = new Thread(receiver);
            tSnd.start(); 
            tRcv.start(); 
            tSnd.join();
            tRcv.join();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
            test1Case();
        }
    }
```

Thanks! I change part of the code to the following and it works now.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        byte[] temp = new byte[10];
        int remain = 10;
        remain -= is.read(temp);
        while(0 != remain)
        {
            remain -= is.read(temp, 10-remain, remain);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            if(temp[j] != d){
                System.out.println("weird!"+" "+i+" "+j+" "+temp[j]);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is on reader side. 
Method `read()` does not guarantee to fill your array. It receives only already available bytes and returns number of bytes that is already got. So you have to read bytes in loop until read returns -1.

Comment: Better still, use `DataInputStream.readFully(),` which already does that.

Comment: Take a look on the implementation of `DataInputStream.readFully()`: it implements the pattern I described. So, it is OK to use it. You can also use various utilities from apache `IOUtils`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the actual number of bytes read when calling `InputStream.read()`  [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5b%5d%29)